# FC Source not found on launch

Tags: android, xml, debugging

I have an app in development and only edited the xml so far and im getting this when i try to debug:

[image: source not found]

Debug:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2306    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2356 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 150    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1244  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5195    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 795  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 562 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#111111"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".NowPlaying" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlcontrols"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bplay"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bprevious"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bplay"
        android:background="@drawable/previous"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bnext"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bplay"
        android:background="@drawable/next"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/brepeat"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bnext"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bnext"
        android:background="@drawable/repeat"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bshuffle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bprevious"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bprevious"
        android:background="@drawable/shuffle"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bplay"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seeker" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtime"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/songProgressBar"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/time"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvalbum"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rlcontrols"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/album"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvartist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvalbum"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/artist"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvartist"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivalbumart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvtitle"
    android:contentDescription="@+string/albumart"
    android:src="@drawable/albumart" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.timmo.tampmusicplayer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.timmo.tampmusicplayer.NowPlaying"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I keep getting this error. Ive tried reinstalling the sdk and the adt/eclipse and nothing. I don't understand what is causing this problem at all.. This was created using the android tools and i cant even get to see my first design...

Answer (score 1):

"Source not found" is not a bug. It's part of eclipse and has nothing to do with your code. It looks like you clicked on the top line of the debug and you were taken here. All "Source not found" indicates is that Eclipse cannot find the source for ActivityThread.java. The real bug if your application isn't starting up will appear in Logcat.

Comment: Basically it just say that there is no source attached.